# Call the native video player in ionic with out using the HTML5

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

How to call the native video player in Ionic framework with AngularJS and without using of HTML5 ?

I tried the following with no success:

```
<ion-content padding="true" overflow-scroll="true">
   <video controls="controls" width="300" preload="metadata" webkit-  playsinline="webkit-playsinline">
      <source src="" type="video/mp4"/>
   </video>
</ion-content>
```